# Manually reading multiple lines of input in terminal

Tags: python, bash

I am writing a python code for a class which needs multiple lines of inputs.

For example I need the input to be in the format:

```
3 14
12 10
12 5
10 5
```

When entering this manually on the terminal, I do not know how to signal an end of input.

I have been working around it by entering the inputs in txt files and reading these.

Comment: What code are you using to read this? A standard approach is to use a specific string (that isn't an otherwise valid input) to tell your code to stop reading. (For example, early text editors in insert mode would read lines of input until you entered a single `.` as a line.)

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to type "end of file".  On Windows, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the control-d, in `bash`, you can also:

```
pythonscript <<EOF
3 14
12 10
12 5
10 5
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

On linux and unix you can find what the EOF char is using

```
stty -a
```

it will show something like

```
...
cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <under>;
...
```

indicating the `eof` is `^D`, which you can also change using `stty`.

Then, you can type `^D` to signal EOF to a process that's reading its input from the terminal.